# Azure pipeline - terratest - ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-pipelines, terratest

i'm facing a (it seams) recurent pbm in Azure Pipeline to run terratest.

While resources are well created the destroyed, when I call an azure.ResourceGroupExists function (or whatever else azure.xxx function) i have the following error :

```
--- FAIL: TestTerraform_RM_resource_group (102.30s)
    resourcegroup.go:15: 
            Error Trace:    resourcegroup.go:15
                                        RM_resource_group_test.go:108
            Error:          Received unexpected error:
                            Invoking Azure CLI failed with the following error: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
            Test:           TestTerraform_RM_resource_group
FAIL
```

Regarding some forum, It seems to be some configuration issue, and I follow all these recomanded configuration :

- set environments variables for terraform :
  -- ARM_CLIENT_ID
  -- ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  -- ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  -- ARM_TENANT_ID
- set the az login in AzureCli task outside the go task for terratest, as it seems that terratest needs 2 differents authentifications : (using service principal client id for this az login)
- For Assert tests, needs the ARM_CLIENT authentification
- for Exists tests, needs the Service connection authentification

here the link I follow :

- https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/issues/454
- https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/tree/master/examples/azure#review-environment-variables
- https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/modules/environment/envvar.go
- https://blog.jcorioland.io/archives/2019/09/25/terraform-microsoft-azure-ci-docker-azure-pipeline.html

bellow my pipeline code, where the TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET is a secret variable of the pipeline

```
runOnce:
  deploy:
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: 'Install Terraform $(TERRAFORM_VERSION)'
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: $(TERRAFORM_VERSION)

    - task: GoTool@0
      displayName: 'Use Go $(GOVERSION)'
      inputs:
        version: $(GOVERSION)
        goPath: $(GOPATH)
        goBin: $(GOBIN)

    - task: Go@0
      displayName: 'Install Go Terratest module'
      inputs:
        command: get
        arguments: '$(TF_LOG) github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform'

    - task: Go@0
      displayName: 'Install Go Assert module'
      inputs:
        command: get
        arguments: '$(TF_LOG) github.com/stretchr/testify/assert'

    - task: Go@0
      displayName: 'Install Go Terratest Azure module'
      inputs:
        command: get
        arguments: '$(TF_LOG) github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure'

    - task: Go@0
      displayName: 'Install Go hashicorp/terraform-json module'
      inputs:
        command: get
        arguments: '$(TF_LOG) github.com/hashicorp/terraform-json'

    - task: Go@0
      displayName: 'Install Go azure-sdk-for-go module'
      inputs:
        command: get
        arguments: '$(TF_LOG) github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go'

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Azure CLI
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal --username $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID) --password $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) --tenant 'f5ff14e7-93c8-49f7-9706-7beea059bd32'

    # Go test command
    - task: Go@0
      displayName: 'Run Go terratest for resource_Modules'
      inputs:
        command: test
        arguments: '$(TF_LOG) $(pathToTerraformRootModule)\resource_group\'
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) #pipeline secret variable
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID)
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
        ARM_TENANT_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_TENANT_ID)
        TF_VAR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID)
        TF_VAR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET: $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID)
        resource_group_name: $(storageAccountResourceGroup)
        storage_account_name: $(storageAccount)
        container_name: $(stateBlobContainer)
        key: '$(MODULE)-$(TF_VAR_APPLICATION)-${{ parameters.Environment }}.tfstate'
```

Bellow my go terratest code :

```
package RM_resource_group_Test

import (
    "testing"
    "os"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

var (
    globalBackendConf = make(map[string]interface{})
    globalEnvVars = make(map[string]string)
)

func TestTerraform_RM_resource_group(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    // terraform Directory
    fixtureFolder := "./"
    
    // input value
    inputStage       := "demo_we"
    inputEnvironment := "DEMO"
    inputApplication := "DEMO"

    // expected value
    expectedName := "z-adf-ftnd-shrd-dm-ew1-rgp42"


    // getting enVars from environment variables
    ARM_CLIENT_ID := os.Getenv("ARM_CLIENT_ID")
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET := os.Getenv("ARM_CLIENT_SECRET")
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID := os.Getenv("ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
    ARM_TENANT_ID := os.Getenv("ARM_TENANT_ID")


    if ARM_CLIENT_ID != "" {
        globalEnvVars["ARM_USE_MSI"] = "false"
        globalEnvVars["ARM_CLIENT_ID"] = ARM_CLIENT_ID
        globalEnvVars["ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"] = ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
        globalEnvVars["ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
        globalEnvVars["ARM_TENANT_ID"] = ARM_TENANT_ID
    }


    // getting backend vars from environment variables
    resource_group_name := os.Getenv("resource_group_name")
    storage_account_name := os.Getenv("storage_account_name")
    container_name := os.Getenv("container_name")
    key := os.Getenv("key")


    if resource_group_name != "" {
        globalBackendConf["use_msi"] = false
        globalBackendConf["resource_group_name"] = resource_group_name
        globalBackendConf["storage_account_name"] = storage_account_name
        globalBackendConf["container_name"] = container_name
        globalBackendConf["key"] = key
    }
    
    // User Terratest to deploy the infrastructure
    terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
        // The path to where our Terraform code is located
        TerraformDir: fixtureFolder,
        // Variables to pass to our Terraform code using -var options
        Vars: map[string]interface{}{
            "STAGE": inputStage,
            "ENVIRONMENT": inputEnvironment,
            "APPLICATION" : inputApplication,
        },


        EnvVars: globalEnvVars,

        // backend values to set when initialziing Terraform
        BackendConfig: globalBackendConf,
        
        // Disable colors in Terraform commands so its easier to parse stdout/stderr
        NoColor: true,

    })



    // website::tag::4::Clean up resources with "terraform destroy". Using "defer" runs the command at the end of the test, whether the test succeeds or fails.
    // At the end of the test, run `terraform destroy` to clean up any resources that were created
    defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

    // website::tag::2::Run "terraform init" and "terraform apply".
    // This will run `terraform init` and `terraform apply` and fail the test if there are any errors
    terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)
    actualName := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "tested_name")
    actualReaderName := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "tested_readerName")
    assert.Equal(t, expectedName, actualName)
    assert.Equal(t, expectedName, actualReaderName)
    
    subscriptionID :=  terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "current_subscription_id")
    exists := azure.ResourceGroupExists(t, expectedName, subscriptionID)
    assert.True(t, exists, "Resource group does not exist")
}
```

I'm sure I miss something in passing my parameters, as always I have the following error, after creating and destroying resources in Azure :

```
--- FAIL: TestTerraform_RM_resource_group (90.75s)
resourcegroup.go:15: 
        Error Trace:    resourcegroup.go:15
                                    RM_resource_group_test.go:108
        Error:          Received unexpected error:
                        Invoking Azure CLI failed with the following error: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
        Test:           TestTerraform_RM_resource_group
```

please, help.

Comment: Hi,  Does the issue occurs Go test command step right? According to the error message it seems that you need to run the command az login, but you have run it. Could set the variable system.debug to true and then share the full log here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and thank-you for answering..

As I figure out earlier, it was a configuration mistake and, after having made some deep excavations on Go Terratest Azure module, I've found these lines that gives all the explanations :

- https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/modules/azure/authorizer.go#L11
  leading to
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authorization#use-environment-based-authentication

So I change my pipeline to this :

```
# Go test command
- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Run Go terratest for resource_Modules'
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '$(TF_LOG) $(pathToTerraformRootModule)\...'
  env:
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID)
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: $(TF_VAR_ARM_TENANT_ID)
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    resource_group_name: $(storageAccountResourceGroup)
    storage_account_name: $(storageAccount)
    container_name: $(stateBlobContainer)
    key: '$(MODULE)-$(TF_VAR_APPLICATION)-${{ parameters.Environment }}.tfstate'
```

And my Go code to this (regarding the envVariables use) :

```
// getting enVars from environment variables
ARM_CLIENT_ID := os.Getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID")
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET := os.Getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET")
ARM_TENANT_ID := os.Getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID")
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID := os.Getenv("ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")

// creating globalEnVars for terraform call through Terratest
if ARM_CLIENT_ID != "" {
    //globalEnvVars["ARM_USE_MSI"] = "true"
    globalEnvVars["ARM_CLIENT_ID"] = ARM_CLIENT_ID
    globalEnvVars["ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"] = ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    globalEnvVars["ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    globalEnvVars["ARM_TENANT_ID"] = ARM_TENANT_ID
}


// getting backend vars from environment variables
resource_group_name := os.Getenv("resource_group_name")
storage_account_name := os.Getenv("storage_account_name")
container_name := os.Getenv("container_name")
key := os.Getenv("key")

// creating globalBackendConf for terraform call through Terratest
if resource_group_name != "" {
    //globalBackendConf["use_msi"] = true
    globalBackendConf["resource_group_name"] = resource_group_name
    globalBackendConf["storage_account_name"] = storage_account_name
    globalBackendConf["container_name"] = container_name
    globalBackendConf["key"] = key
}

// User Terratest to deploy the infrastructure
terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
    // website::tag::1::Set the path to the Terraform code that will be tested.
    // The path to where our Terraform code is located
    TerraformDir: fixtureFolder,
    // Variables to pass to our Terraform code using -var options
    Vars: map[string]interface{}{
        "STAGE": inputStage,
        "ENVIRONMENT": inputEnvironment,
        "APPLICATION" : inputApplication,
        //"configuration" : inputConfiguration,
    },


    // globalvariables for user account 
    EnvVars: globalEnvVars,

    // backend values to set when initialziing Terraform
    BackendConfig: globalBackendConf,
    
    // Disable colors in Terraform commands so its easier to parse stdout/stderr
    NoColor: true,

})
```

And all goes right !
Hopes this could help others.

Thanks again.

[EDIT] To be more explicit :

Go and Terraform uses two differents methods for Azure authentification.

** Terraform authentification is explained bellow :

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform

** Go authentification is explained bellow :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authorization#use-environment-based-authentication

** Terratest is using both authentification methods regarding the work it has to be done :

- azure existences tests uses Go azure authentification :

  - https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/modules/azure/authorizer.go#L11
- terraform commands uses terraform authentification :

  - https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/0d654bd2ab781a52e495f61230cf892dfba9731b/modules/terraform/cmd.go#L12
  - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform

so both authentification methods have to be implemented

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)